# .Net Core , c# and Fitnesse Fit fixtures

Tags: c#, fitnesse, acceptance-testing, user-acceptance-testing

---

Hello All,

I'm trying to create Fitnesse Tests using c# and .Net Core.
I'm unable to find any Nuget Packages for .Net Core.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The port to .Net Core has been completed and is available as version 2.7 in Nuget.